# Doctrine Mongo search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm

On Mongo DB manual page, it says, "**to match on a phrase, as opposed to individual terms, enclose the phrase in escaped double quotes (\")**"

"\"ssl certificate\""

How can I do this with Doctrine query builder?
At moment, I do query like below:

```
$name = '\"'.$name.'\"';
$qb->field('entityName')->text($name)->getQuery()->toArray();
```

**above Doctrine query returns empty []**,
query used by Doctrine as below:

```
array:5 [
    "type" => 1
    "select" => array:1 [
        "entityName" => 1
    ]
    "limit" => 10
    "query" => array:1 [
        "$text" => array:1 [
        "$search" => "\"oxford tru\""
        ]
    ]
    "newObj" => []
]
```

if I do the query in mongo shell,

```
db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "\"oxford tru\""}},{entityName:1})
```

**above mongo shell command returns 5 results**

Comment: Have you tried `$name = '"'.$name.'"';`? There's no need to escape `"` in `'` (contrary to mongo shell where you escape quotes within `"``)

Comment: @malarzm, can you put your comment to answer section? so I can mark it as right answer.

Comment: Done, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$name = '"'.$name.'"';` There's no need to escape `"` in `'` (contrary to mongo shell where you escape quotes within `"`)